# How to create an abstract class that will handle basic CRUD with GreenDAO for any Entity model

Tags: java, greendao

I would like to create an abstract class that will call the Dao to insert any entity object in order to avoid to write duplicate code in every class that implements `IRepository`,

```
public abstract class DBStore<T> implements IRepository {
    DaoMaster daoMaster;
    Class<T> entityClass; 

    public DBStore(DaoMaster daoMaster, Class<T> entityClass) {
        this.daoMaster = daoMaster;
        this.entityClass = entityClass;
    }

    @Override
    public void add(Entity entity) {
        DaoSession session = this.daoMaster.newSession();
        AbstractDao<?, ?> dao = session.getDao(this.entityClass);
        dao.insert(entity);  // cannot pass entity as parameter because insert() expects capture<?>
    }

    // Other CRUD methods
}
```

I don't understand what syntax should I use to specify that the variable `entity` is what `insert()` expects.

Comment: AbstractDao <?, ?> - what are those two generic params? Logically they are E - the entity type, and the primary key type - so, if you use Integer as PK, then declare AbstractDao <E, Integer>

Comment: DaoSession already covers some of this. It's not just access to DAOs, but also provides CRUD methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I got it working by specifiying `DBStore<T extends Entity> implements IRepository<T>`
and casting `AbstractDao<?, ?>` to `AbstractDao<T, Long>`

Here is the complete code:

```
public abstract class DBStore<T extends Entity> implements IRepository<T> {
    DaoMaster daoMaster;
    Class<T> entityClass;

    public DBStore(DaoMaster daoMaster, Class<T> entityClass) {
        this.daoMaster = daoMaster;
        this.entityClass = entityClass;
    }

    @Override
    public void add(T entity) {
        this.getSession().insert(entity);
    }

    @Override
    public T getById(long id) {
        AbstractDao<T, Long> dao = this.getDao();
        return dao.load(id);
    }

    //other methods

    protected AbstractDao<T, Long> getDao(){
        DaoSession session = this.daoMaster.newSession();
        return (AbstractDao<T, Long>) session.getDao(this.entityClass);
    }

    protected DaoSession getSession(){
        return this.daoMaster.newSession();
    }
}
```